# Prove that $ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-x^2\sin^2 \alpha}dx = \frac{\pi}{4\cos^2 \frac{\alpha}{2}}$.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Prove that $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-x^2\sin^2 \alpha}\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi}{4\cos^2 \dfrac{\alpha}{2}}$.

$\bf{My\; attempt}::$ Let $x = \sin \theta$, then $\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x = \cos \theta \mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}\theta.$

Let $$I = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-x^2\sin^2\alpha}\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x,$$

then
\begin{align}
I& = \int _{0}^{1}\frac{\cos \theta }{1-\sin^2 \theta \cdot \sin^2 \alpha}\cdot \cos \theta \mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}\theta \\
 & = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\cos ^2 \theta }{1-\sin^2 \theta \cdot \sin ^2 \alpha}\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}\theta \\
 & = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sec^2 \theta}{\sec^4 \theta -\tan^2 \theta \cdot \sec^2 \theta \cdot \sin^2 \alpha}\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}\theta \\
 & = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sec^2 \theta }{\left(1+\tan ^2 \theta\right)^2-\tan^2 \theta \cdot \sec^2 \theta\cdot \sin^2 \alpha}\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}\theta.
\end{align}

Let $\tan \theta = t$ and $\sec^2 \theta \mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}\theta = \mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}t$ we get

$$I = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{(1+t^2)^2-t^2 (1+t^2)\sin^2 \alpha}\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}t.$$

Now How can I solve after that

Help Required

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a much nicer way than my first attempt. Use $x=\sin(\theta)$ and $u=\tan(\theta)$
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-x^2\sin^2(\alpha)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^2(\theta)}{1-\sin^2(\theta)\sin^2(\alpha)}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\sec^2(\theta)-\tan^2(\theta)\sin^2(\alpha)}\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{1+\tan^2(\theta)\cos^2(\alpha)}\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}\tan(\theta)}{(1+\tan^2(\theta)\cos^2(\alpha))(1+\tan^2(\theta))}\\
&=\frac1{\sin^2(\alpha)}\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\frac1{1+\tan^2(\theta)}-\frac{\cos^2(\alpha)}{1+\tan^2(\theta)\cos^2(\alpha)}\right)\,\mathrm{d}\tan(\theta)\\
&=\frac1{\sin^2(\alpha)}\int_0^\infty\left(\frac1{1+u^2}-\frac{\cos^2(\alpha)}{1+u^2\cos^2(\alpha)}\right)\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac1{\sin^2(\alpha)}\left(\frac\pi2-\frac\pi2\cos(\alpha)\right)\\
&=\frac\pi2\frac1{1+\cos(\alpha)}\\
&=\frac\pi{4\cos^2(\alpha/2)}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 10):

Substitute $x=\dfrac{t}{\sqrt{\cos \alpha+t^2}}$. Then
$\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x= \dfrac{\cos \alpha\ \mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}t}{(\cos \alpha+t^2)^{3/2}}$ and

\begin{align}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-x^2\sin^2 \alpha}\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}x
=& \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{\cos \alpha}\ \frac1{t^2} }{(t^2+ \frac1{t^2} )\cos \alpha +(1+\cos^2\alpha)}\overset{t\to 1/t}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}t}\\
 =& \ \frac{\sqrt{\cos \alpha}}2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}(1-\frac1{t} )}{(t-\frac1{t} )^2\cos \alpha +(1+\cos \alpha)^2}\\
 =& \ \frac{\pi}{2(1+\cos \alpha)}.\\
\end{align}

Comment: That is a short and smart way! +1).

Comment: Should the last second line be $ \ \frac{\sqrt{\cos \alpha}}2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}(t-\frac1{t} )}{(t-\frac1{t} )^2\cos \alpha +(1+\cos \alpha)^2}$?

Answer (score 5):

Here is another method to solve the problem by using residue. Suppose $\alpha\in(0,\pi/2)$. Using $x=\sin(\theta)$ and $u=\tan(\theta), z=e^{i\theta}$, one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-x^2\sin^2(\alpha)}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=&\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^2(\theta)}{1-\sin^2(\theta)\sin^2(\alpha)}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=&\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\frac{1+\cos(2\theta)}{2}}{1-\frac{1-\cos(2\theta)}{2}\sin^2(\alpha)}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=&\frac14\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1+\cos(\theta)}{2-(1-\cos(\theta))\sin^2(\alpha)}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=&\frac14\int_{|z|=1}\frac{1+\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}}{2-(1-\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2})\sin^2(\alpha)}\frac{1}{iz}\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=&\frac1{4i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{(z+1)^2}{z[4+(z-1)^2\sin^2(\alpha)]}\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=&\frac1{4i\sin^2(\alpha)}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{(z+1)^2}{z(z+\tan^2(\alpha/2))(z+\cot^2(\alpha/2))}\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&=&\frac1{4i\sin^2(\alpha)}2\pi i\bigg[\text{Res}(\frac{(z+1)^2}{(z+\tan^2(\alpha/2))(z+\cot^2(\alpha/2))},z=0)+\text{Res}(\frac{(z+1)^2}{z(z+\cot^2(\alpha/2))},z=-\tan^2(\alpha/2)\bigg]\\
&=&\frac{\pi}{4\cos^2(\alpha/2)}.
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 2):

Letting $x=\sin \theta$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
I &=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{d t}{\left(1+t^2\right)^2-\left(1+t^2\right) t^2 \sin ^2 \alpha} \\
&=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{d x}{t^4 \cos ^2 \alpha+\left(1+\cos ^2 \alpha\right) t^2+1}
\end{aligned}
$$
Dividing both denominator and numerator of the integrand gives
$$
\begin{aligned}
I&=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\frac{1}{t^2}}{t^2 \cos ^2 \alpha+\frac{1}{t^2}+\left(1+\cos ^2 \alpha\right)} d t \\
&=\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\left(\cos \alpha+\frac{1}{t^2}\right)-\left(\cos \alpha-\frac{1}{t^2} \right)}{t^2 \cos ^2 \alpha+\frac{1}{t^2}+\left(1+\cos ^2 \alpha\right)} d t \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\int_0^{\infty} \frac{d\left(t \cos \alpha-\frac{1}{t}\right)}{\left(t \cos \alpha-\frac{1}{t}\right)^2+(1+\cos \alpha)^2}+\int_0^{\infty} \frac{d\left(t \cos \alpha+\frac{1}{t}\right)}{\left.\left(t \cos \alpha+\frac{1}{t}\right)^2+(1-\cos \alpha t)\right]}\right] \\
&=\frac{1}{2(1+\cos \alpha)}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{t \cos \alpha-\frac{1}{t}}{1+\cos \alpha}\right)\right]_0^{\infty} \\
&=\frac{1}{4 \cos ^2 \frac{\alpha}{2}}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \\
&=\frac{\pi}{4 \cos ^2 \frac{\alpha}{2}}
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

An attempt, which I do not think leads to a solution for calculating it $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}{\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-x^2 \sin^2 x}}dx$ with complex analysis.

First, we do the replacement:
$$
\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}{\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-x^2 \sin^2 x}}dx = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{\sin^2 t dt}{1-\cos^2 t \sin^2(\cos t)}}
$$

In the last with replacement $x=\cos t$, $0\leqslant t \leqslant \frac{\pi}{2}$, $y=\pi-x$, then
$$
\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{\sin^2 t dt}{1-\cos^2 t \sin^2(\cos t)}} = \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}{\frac{\sin^2t dt}{1-\cos^2 t \sin^2(\cos t)}}
$$

So
$$
\displaystyle 2 \int_{0}^{1}{\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-x^2 \sin^2 x}}dx = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{\sin^2t dt}{1-\cos^2 t \sin^2(\cos t)}} + \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}{\frac{\sin^2 t dt}{1-\cos^2 t \sin^2(\cos t)}}
$$
$$
\displaystyle = \int_{0}^{\pi}{\frac{\sin^2 t dt}{1-\cos^2 t \sin^2(\cos t)}}
$$

The last with the replacement $u=2\pi-x$:
$$
\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi}{\frac{\sin^2 t dt}{1-\cos^2 t \sin^2(\cos t)}} = \int_{\pi}^{2\pi}{\frac{\sin^2 t dt}{1-\cos^2 t \sin^2(\cos t)}} \Rightarrow 4\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-x^2 \sin^2 x}}dx = \int_{0}^{2\pi}{\frac{\sin^2 t dt}{1-\cos^2 t \sin^2(\cos t)}}
$$

Now we consider the replacement $z=e^{it}$, $dt=\frac{dz}{iz}$:
$$
\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi}{\frac{dt}{1-\cos^2 t \sin^2(\cos t)}} = \frac{16}{i}\oint_{C} z\left[16z^2+\left(z^2+1 \right)^2 \left(e^{\displaystyle{i\frac{z^2+1}{2z}}} - e^{\displaystyle{-i\frac{z^2+1}{2z}}} \right) \right]^{-1} dz
$$
where $C$ is the counterclockwise unit circle, and the formulas $\cos \theta =\frac{e^{i\theta }-e^{-i\theta }}{2}$, $\sin \theta =\frac{e^{i\theta }-e^{-i\theta }}{2i}$ were used
Because all poles are within our circle (by Wolfram) with the use of
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n}{\text{Res}\left(f,0 \right)} = -\text{Res}\left(f, \infty \right) = -\text{Res}\left(-\frac{1}{z^2}f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right), 0\right)
$$

It is enough to find its $-\frac{1}{z^2}f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$ residue at zero:
$$
-\frac{1}{z^2}f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) = -\frac{z}{16z^2+\left(z^2+1 \right)A^{2}\left(z \right)}, \quad A\left(z \right) = e^{\frac{i}{2}\left(z+\frac{1}{z} \right)} - e^{-\frac{i}{2}\left(z+\frac{1}{z} \right)}
$$

$$
\frac{8z}{16z^2+\left(z^2+1 \right)A^{2}\left(z \right)} = \frac{1}{4z-i\left(z^2+1 \right)A\left(z \right)} + \frac{1}{4z+i\left(z^2+1 \right)A\left(z \right)}
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{4z}\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{i\left(z^2+1 \right)A\left(z \right)}{4z}} + \frac{1}{1+\frac{i\left(z^2+1 \right)A\left(z \right)}{4z}}\right)
$$

Now, we will use the familiar:
$$
\frac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{z^n}, \quad e^{z} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{z^n}{n!}}
$$

Consequently:
$$
\frac{1}{\displaystyle{1-\frac{i\left(z^2+1 \right)A\left(z \right)}{4z}}} + \frac{1}{\displaystyle{1+\frac{i\left(z^2+1 \right)A\left(z \right)}{4z}}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{i\left(z^2+1 \right)A\left(z \right)}{4z} \right)^n + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{-i\left(z^2+1 \right)A\left(z \right)}{4z} \right)^n}}
$$

$$
= 2\sum_{n=0,n=2m}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{i\left(z^2+1 \right)A\left(z \right)}{4z} \right)^n}
$$

$$
= 2\sum_{n=0,n=2m}^{\infty}{\left(\sum_{k=1,k=2m+1}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{i}{2} \right)^{k+1} \frac{1}{k!}\left(z+\frac{1}{z} \right)^{k+1}} \right)}^n
$$

Therefore, we are looking for the constant coefficient of the above performance. So now:
$$
\left(z+\frac{1}{z} \right)^{k+1} = \binom{k+1}{\frac{k+1}{2}} + \sum_{j=2,j=2m}^{k+1}{\binom{k+1}{\frac{k+j+1}{2}}\left(z^{j}+z^{-j} \right)} \left(\frac{i}{2} \right)^{k+1} \frac{1}{k!}\left(z+\frac{1}{z} \right)^{k+1}
$$

$$
= \left(\frac{i}{2} \right)^{k+1} \frac{1}{k!}\binom{k+1}{\frac{k+1}{2}} + \left(\frac{i}{2} \right)^{k+1} \frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=2,j=2m}^{k+1}{\binom{k+1}{\frac{k+j+1}{2}}\left(z^{j}+z^{-j} \right)}
$$

So, the final sum is:
$$
\sum_{n=0,n=2m}^{\infty}{\left(\sum_{k=1,k=2m+1}^{\infty}{\left(\left(\frac{i}{2} \right)^{k+1} \frac{1}{k!}\binom{k+1}{\frac{k+1}{2}} \right)} + \sum_{k=1,k=2m+1}^{\infty}{\left(\left(\frac{i}{2} \right)^{k+1} \frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=2,j=2m}^{k+1}{\binom{k+1}{\frac{k+j+1}{2}}\left(z^{j}+z^{-j} \right)} \right)} \right)}^n
$$

Within it is contained definitely the:
$$
\sum_{n=0,n=2m}^{\infty}{\left(\sum_{k=1,k=2m+1}^{\infty}{\left(\left(\frac{i}{2} \right)^{k+1} \frac{1}{k!}\binom{k+1}{\frac{k+1}{2}} \right)} \right)}^n
$$

Similar:
$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\frac{\cos^2 t dt}{1-\cos^2 t \sin^2 \left(\cos t \right)}} = \frac{4}{i} \oint_{C} \frac{\left(z^2+1 \right)^2}{z\left(16z^2+\left(z^2+1 \right)^2 A\left(z \right) \right)}dz$$

residue at 0 of $$\displaystyle -\frac{\displaystyle{z\left(z+\frac{1}{z} \right)^2}}{16z^2+\left(z^2+1 \right)^2 A\left(\frac{1}{z} \right)}$$

$$\displaystyle \frac{8\displaystyle{z\left(z+\frac{1}{z} \right)^2}}{16z^2+\left(z^2+1 \right)^2 A\left(\frac{1}{z} \right)}=\frac{1}{4z}\left(\frac{\displaystyle{\left(z+\frac{1}{z} \right)^2}}{\displaystyle{1-\frac{i}{4}\left(z+\frac{1}{z} \right)A\left(z \right)}}+\frac{\displaystyle{\left(z+\frac{1}{z} \right)^2}}{\displaystyle{1+\frac{i}{4}\left(z+\frac{1}{z} \right)A\left(z \right)}} \right)$$
$$= \frac{1}{4z}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\left(\frac{i}{4} \right)^n\left(z+\frac{1}{z} \right)^{n+2}}A^n \left(z \right) + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\left(-\frac{i}{4} \right)^n\left(z+\frac{1}{z} \right)^{n+2}}A^n \left(z \right) \right)
$$

And he continues with the same logic. I wonder if constant terms can be calculated in the final sums...