# integral $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-x^2\sin^2(a)}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I couldn't do anything to the $\sin(a)$. How do I approach?

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-x^2\sin^2(a)}dx.$$

Comment: The change $x=\cos\phi$ and $I=\int_0^{\pi/2}$$\frac{d \phi}{1/cos^2\phi-\tan^2\phi\sin^2a}$. Next change $t=\tan\phi$

Comment: Is this the same integral as here: [Prove that $ \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-x^2\sin^2 \alpha}dx = \frac{\pi}{4\cos^2 \frac{\alpha}{2}}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/550145)?

Comment: BTW you can try searching for similar posts [using Approach Zero](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Csqrt%7B1-x%5E2%7D%7D%7B1-x%5E2%5Csin%5E2(a)%7Ddx%24&p=1) or [SearchOnMath](https://www.searchonmath.com/result?query=$%7B%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B1%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Csqrt%7B1-x%5E2%7D%7D%7B1-x%5E2%5Csin%5E2(a)%7Ddx%7D$) See also: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**

Let $k=\sin a$, and use $x=\sin\theta$. Then you have
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{1-k^2x^2} \, dx & = \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^2\theta}{1-k^2\sin^2\theta} \, d\theta\\ 
& = \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cot^2\theta}{\csc^2\theta-k^2} \, d\theta\\
&= \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\csc^2\theta-1}{\cot^2\theta+(1-k^2)} \, d\theta\\
&= \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\csc^2\theta}{\cot^2\theta+(1-k^2)} \, d\theta - \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{\cot^2\theta+(1-k^2)} \, d\theta\\
\end{align*}
Can you take it from here?

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I have tried to interpret the policy as best as I can and have tried to stick to it's core to the best of my interpretation. As you can see I haven't given the answer to the question. OP had difficulty in handling the constant $\sin^2 a$ and I tried to help OP resolve that issue.

Comment: With all due respect, I have seen many including you, answer questions which were not any more elaborately posed so at best it creates confusion and also it leaves an impression that rules are different for different people. I hope you will understand that my criticism is not directed towards you or any individual but more to the fact that the policy is very ambiguous at best.

Comment: Your criticism would have been correct a long time ago, but I have not been answering questions such as this one for quite some time now.